# Excel VBA - delete string content up to *word*

Tags: string, vba, excel

I'm trying to delete string content up to a certain word contained within the string. For example

```
"Emily has wild flowers. They are red and blue."
```

I'd like to use VBA in order to replace that with

```
"They are red and blue."
```

i.e. remove all the content up to the word "They". I don't know the string content and the number of characters contained in it.

I'm not sure how to do this and I'd really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Dim s As String
s = "Emily has wild flowers. They are red and blue."

Dim indexOfThey As Integer

indexOfThey = InStr(1, s, "They")


Dim finalString As String
finalString = Right(s, Len(s) - indexOfThey + 1)
```

Comment: note that you don't need to calculate the length of the string. `finalString = Mid(s, indexOfThey)`, as with Mid, the length is optional

Comment: This will also catch part words.  If you were searching for "go" in "I'll take the algorithm to go.", you will end up with "gorithm to go".

Answer (score 3):

Simple example of dropping all text before value in string.

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim strOrig As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    strOrig = "The Quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs"
    strReplace = "jumped"

    MsgBox (DropTextBefore(strOrig, strReplace))

End Sub

Public Function DropTextBefore(strOrigin As String, strFind As String)
    Dim strOut As String
    Dim intFindPosition As Integer
    'case insensitive search
    'could made it so that case sensitivity is a parameter but this gets the idea across.
    If strOrigin <> "" And strFind <> "" Then
        intFindPosition = InStr(UCase(strOrigin), UCase(strFind))
        strOut = Right(strOrigin, Len(strOrigin) - (intFindPosition + Len(strFind) - 1))
    Else
      strOut = "Error Empty Parameter in function call was encountered."
    End If
    DropTextBefore = strOut
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If the word is fixed, like "They" in the above example, you can simply do

1. CTRL + H (Replace)
2. *They (your word with a star)

in the Find box. The star * is a wildcard character which can be called as - of anything before or after (if added at end) the word.

Cautious: Take care when you have duplicate words in the same cell.

Comment: Thanks but the application I need this for is more complex and requires to be VBA driven.

Comment: Why is it downvoted...where was it written in the question that this is a complex and requried VBA driven stratergy....

Comment: I'm going to guess that "I'd like to use VBA" as well as the `vba` and `excel-vba` tags indicates VBA, plus the fact that your approach is dangerous, and it doesn't address the fact that the text before the word "They" may change.  It misses the point of the question, and doesn't safely answer it.

Comment: Oh my Goodness...I should have read the question properly...a lesson

Comment: I upvoted this because I went into it planning on using VBA to solve it and this answer showed me I was over-complicating it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked great for me:

```
Sub remove_until()

Dim i, lrowA, remChar As Long
Dim mString As String

lrowA = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lrowA

mString = Cells(i, 1).Value


    If InStr(mString, "They") > 0 Then

    remChar = Len(mString) - InStr(mString, "They") + 1

    Cells(i, 2).Value = Left(mString, Len(mString) - remChar)

    End If


Next

End Sub
```