# Excel VBA - delete string content after *word*

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete string content before a certain word contained within the string. For example

```
master_of_desaster@live.de
```

I'd like to use VBA in order to replace that with

```
master_of_desaster
```

Everything after the "word" (@) should be removed, including the "word" itself.

I found a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18402931/4684797), but he asks the opposite.

Comment: find the `@` using `Instr` function. Then, just use `Left` of the original string up to the result of `Instr`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA, excel cut a part from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085441/vba-excel-cut-a-part-from-a-string)

Comment: If you are doing this on cells, a simple Find/Replace may well be fastest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
email = "master_of_desaster@live.de"

ret = Left(email, InStr(1, email, "@") - 1)
```

**Result**: master_of_desaster

Thanks to [Shai Rado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6344363/shai-rado)

Answer (score 4):

`=split("master_of_desaster@live.de","@")(0)`

Comment: If you add comments to it, then i will accept it as the solution. (I understand it, but will others do?)

Answer (score 2):

A bit hacky but fast ( most Windows API accept zero terminated strings )

```
ret = Replace("master_of_disaster@live.de", "@", vbNullChar, , 1) ' Chr(0)
```

I usually use the Split method but with Limit:

```
ret = Split("master_of_disaster@live.de", "@", 2)(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun - a regex approach.

```
Public Sub reg()

    Dim re_pattern As String
    Dim re As RegExp
    Dim email As String
    Dim match As Object

    Set re = New RegExp

    email = "master_of_desaster@live.de"
    re_pattern = "(.*)@.*"

    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = re_pattern
    End With

    Set match = re.Execute(email)

    Debug.Print match.Item(0).SubMatches(0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ret = evaluate("left(" & string & ", search(""@"", " & string & ") - 1)")
```