# How to delete content in a cell after a certain word

Tags: excel, vba, string

I've names and their corresponding salary amounts next to each other.

I need to delete everything in the name cell after the name.

Data sample:

[image]

I need everything after "ABC Staff" deleted including the word itself, and I need to apply that to a large quantity of names in a column all at once.

I've found an answer to the first part here:

[Excel VBA - delete string content after *word*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593007/excel-vba-delete-string-content-after-word)

How do I get this to work for all of the names at once?

```
name = "NAME ABC Staff xyz" 
ret = Left(Name, InStr(1, name, "ABC Staff") - 1)
Result: NAME
```

Comment: Can you set up a sample file so we know how your data looks? We need to see the input & desired output. Also, if you have the first part, please share the code you have

Comment: Thank you for your quick response urdearboy. I've added a picture of what the data looks like to the OP - The output can be Column C of the same worksheet.

Comment: Double check - no photo has been added

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to shift enter to give you the code needed:

email = "master_of_desaster@live.de"

ret = Left(email, InStr(1, email, "@") - 1)

Result: master_of_desaster. This removes everything after the @ including the @

Comment: You photo does not match the code you provided. Please take the time to upload sample data that actually reflects your real data... your photo & comment do not agree with each other. Nowhere in your photo is an email address, let alone the `@` symbol.

Comment: The code provided was for an e-mail. Here's what the code would look like for my data:

name = "NAME ABC Staff xyz"

ret = Left(name, InStr(1, name, "ABC Staff") - 1) Result: NAME. My apologies for confusion. I would like to know how to apply that to say 600 names at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LR As Long, MyCell As Range

LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each MyCell In ws.Range("A2:A" & LR)
    If InStr(MyCell, "ABC Staff") Then
        MyCell.Offset(, 3) = Left(MyCell, InStr(MyCell, "ABC Staff") - 2)
    ElseIf InStr(MyCell, "Private") Then
        MyCell.Offset(, 3) = Left(MyCell, InStr(MyCell, "Private") - 2)
    Else
        'What if "ABC Staff" nor "Private" exist in the cell?
    End If
Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you once more urdearboy. I'm running into a "For loop not initialized" on the "Next MyCell" Line. It worked for the first row (A2) but not those after it.

Comment: I made sure to update the sheet name. For some reason that error went away, it's now been replaced with an "invalid procedure call or argument" error in the line above it. It cycled through the first 5 names, and then hit a name which was followed by the word "private" (a few of their accounts are labeled as such). Putting that in lieu of "ABC Staff" did not work, returning that error.

Comment: It appears so. Only about 5 of the 650 names are followed by that, I was hoping that I would be able to just run the code with "Private" instead of "ABC Staff" when that occurred. I'm sorry for being so handhold-needy, I barely understand this stuff but plan on learning more in the time saved by automating this reconciliation. I'd be happy, if you were willing, to venmo you $5 (if you have it) for the help, you could send your handle to a temporary email

Comment: @kltk7 not necessary - just please make sure to *accept* the solution if we getting it working :)

Comment: Yes I would like everything before that word. I tried removing that row and setting it aside and I'm still getting the invalid procedure call or argument error unfortunately. And I most certainly will accept the solution hehe I do at least understand the necessity of that part of stack overflow ^^

Comment: With the new code? This code is working on my after adjusting to added criteria (Private)

Comment: @urdearboy Pardon me for butting in, but what is `InStr(MyCell, "ABC Staff") - 2` supposed to return? Isn't a `Boolean` minus a `Long`? or even if it does return 1 or 0, aren't you going to get a negative number?

Comment: I am glad to say that it is working. I found one other exception (a new one I wasn't aware of), but with your code I was simply able to add that to the code. My sincere thanks again for your help, it is truly appreciated. I will accept the solution :)!

Comment: `InStr` is like `Search`. On OPs test string, this will return **6** which is fed into the `Left` function. Subtracting 2 will land us with **4** which is the length of the output OP wants (`Name`) @dwirony

Comment: @urdearboy I see now - for some reason I was thinking `InStr` returned 1 or 0.

Comment: @dwirony I've heard mixed things about using `InStr` as a boolean test. Either way, 0 returns `FALSE` and **everything else** returns `TRUE`. So if nothing is found, then you would be correct. You can use `InStr` either way